# How can I allow Chrome to POST data before a web page has completely loaded?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a lot of rows in a table that need to be displayed in Google Chrome and would like to know if it is possible for Google Chrome to POST data to a web form while that table-data is still in the process of loading.

Right now, Google Chrome will not let me post the data while it is still trying to display the table-data (loading animation), but in Firefox, I have no issues at all.

Any settings or tweaks available to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at  `stale-while-revalidate` flag by entering `chrome://flags` in your URL bar.

Maybe that can help, but it doesn't do so well on *large* tables in my experience.

*For the record, `chrome://chrome-urls` has **all** of tweakable settings available.*

Comment: Where is this flag located?  I am on Windows 7.  Not very familiar with Chrome.

Comment: chrome://flags in a chrome url bar (the chrome:// is the handler needed much like http:// ftp:// etc etc )

Comment: would it be the `stale-while-revalidate` flag?

Comment: That did exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: chrome://chrome-urls  for the record has ALL the extra goodies that can be tweaked

Comment: @Kevin Panko  which marking is that that you used on the "stale-while-revalidate" been trying to figure out all the formatting of text stuff here. tia

Comment: @linuxdev2013 You can view the source by clicking http://superuser.com/revisions/11de08ce-92aa-47b6-b429-5fec1349f504/view-source The user guide is http://superuser.com/editing-help and the answer to your question is to use the \`backquotes\`